# How to fix grub not being able to boot Windows Boot Manager on dual boot system

Tags: debian, boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

Dual booting Windows 10 and debian. Win10 is on C: and debian is on a partition on E:. BIOS boot priority has debian over Windows Boot Manager, so I am able to load into grub.

After first getting debian set up, Windows Boot Manager wasn't showing up in grub at all. I looked around and added `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to the grub file using `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and `sudo update-grub`. Windows Boot Manager now is an option in grub.

However, when trying to boot into Windows Boot Manager (after restarting inside of debian), I am met with two errors from grub:
`error: no such device` and `error: file '/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmfgw.efi' not found.` Strangely, though, if I instead choose to load into BIOS first, and then exit BIOS, the Windows Boot Manager option works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair            
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @drew-k did you find the solution? can you please help me i have the same problem.

Comment: @HemantJaiman Yeah, I found a solution that worked for me, although it wasn't the one I was looking for. After messing around with things and digging a bit deeper, the problem ended up being that GRUB could not find the windows boot manager device because they were on different drives. I moved my linux installation to my C: drive (where my Windows also is) and it works fine now.